# Can't change update settings on elementary OS

Tags: upgrade, elementary-os

I can't update elementary OS, when I try to change the settings 'Install updates from', none of the check boxes will check, it stays like the following image. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please see if this helps you.

[Software Update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/why-cant-i-enable-the-various-upstream-repositories/4254#4254)

I have this problem, and the solution does not work work though.

Answer (score -1):

When you click on one of those check boxes, it should ask you to authenticate - either:

- with your password (if you are a super user)
- or with a super user's password (if a super user has been created)
- or with the root password (which probably hasn't been set up as it's Ubuntu based).

If that fails, start a `terminal` and enter the following:

```
sudo software-center
```

It will ask for your user password and open the software-center for you with the required privileges to change the settings.

Alternatively, and if the above doesn't work, you can edit the `apt` repository configuration directly by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  The disabled repositories start with a single `#`.  Remove this `#` to enable the repository.

Comment: That didn't do anything :/ Basically, as soon as I check one, it unchecks itself.

Comment: I didn't see a software.list file, just sources.list

Comment: My apologies - that was a typo. Edit the sources.list